# Rails - Query table with array of IDs and order based on the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Let me describe with simple example.

I have a list of numbers:

ex: `list = [ 3, 1, 2 ]`

and I have a table in DB named `Products` which have 3 rows with `product_id` = `1`, `2`and `3`.

Now I need to query `Products` sort by `list` values `(3,1,2)` so the result will be:

product_3
product_1
product_2

Query will be like:
product.sort(list) or product.order(list) or some other alternative pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
list = [3, 1, 2]

Product.where(product_id: list).sort_by { |p| list.find_index(p.product_id) })
```